# Handlebars - multiple objects

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

It is my first time trying out handlebars. Somehow I'm not able to get the array in one of the object.

This is what I get currently:

> Eric Alan

This is how I expect the output to be like:

> Eric 2019-01-01  Eric Type a Eric  2019-12-31 Eric Type a Alan
> 2020-01-01 Alan Type a

Below is the working code but i unable to get the date and type from {{list_of_date}}:

```js
$(function() {
  var source = $("#document-template").html();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
  var html = template(data);
  $('#DocumentResults').html(html);
});



var data = [{
  users: [{
    name: 'Eric',
    list_of_date: [{
      "2019-01-01": [{
        "id": "1",
        "type": "Eric Type a",
      }],
      "2019-12-31": [{
        "id": "2",
        "type": "Eric Type b",
      }]
    }],
  }, {
    name: 'Alan',
    list_of_date: [{
      "2020-01-01": [{
        "id": "1",
        "type": "Alan Type a",
      }]
    }],
  }]
}];
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.0.0/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="DocumentResults"></div>
<script id="document-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div>
    {{#each this}} 
      {{#users}} 
        {{name}} 
      {{/users}} 
    
      {{#list_of_date}} 
        {{type}}
      {{/list_of_date}} 
      
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be:

```
{{#each this}} 
 {{#each users as | user |}} 
  {{user.name}} 
  {{#each user.list_of_date as | userDateItem |}}
   {{#each userDateItem as |toDisplay|}}
    {{@key}}
    {{toDisplay.[0].type}}
   {{/each}}
  {{/each}}
 {{/each}} 
{{/each}}
```